# Downsample an Image

Tags: c++, c, image-processing, imagefilter

I'm trying to downsample an image by 2, the image i assumed that it is greyscale, so I will work only with one channel, I tried to average 4 pixels, then put the resultant in the destImage. I don't know how to fill the destImage correctly. Kindly find the code here:

```
void downsizeRow(unsigned char *srcImage, unsigned char *dstImage, int srcWidth )
{

    unsigned char *srcPtr = srcImage;
    unsigned char *dstPtr = dstImage;

    int stride = srcWidth;
    int b;
    for (int i = 0; i< 4; i++)
    {

        b  = srcPtr[0]+srcPtr[1] + srcPtr[stride + 0] + srcPtr[stride + 1] ;

        srcPtr++;
        dstPtr[0] = (uint8_t)((b + 2)/4);;
        dstPtr++;
    }

}

void downscaleImage( unsigned char *srcImage, unsigned char *dstImage, int srcWidth, int dstHeight, int dstWidth)
{

    unsigned char *srcPtr=srcImage;
    unsigned char *dstPtr=dstImage;

    int in_stride = dstWidth;
    int out_stride = dstHeight;

    for (int j=0;j<dstHeight;j++)
    {
        downsizeRow(srcPtr, dstPtr, srcWidth);  // in_stride is needed
        // as the function requires access to iptr+in_stride
        srcPtr+=in_stride * 2;
        dstImage+=out_stride;
    }
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);

    unsigned char srcimage[4*4];
    unsigned char dstimage[2*2];


    for (int i = 0; i<4*4; i++)
    {
        srcimage[i] = 25;
    }
    std::cout<<"source Image \n"<<std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<4*4; i++)
    {

        std::cout<<srcimage[i];
    }

    downscaleImage(srcimage, dstimage, 4,4,2);
    std::cout<<"dest Image"<<std::endl;
    for (int i = 0; i<2*2; i++)
    {

    //    std::cout<<dstimage[i];
    }

    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Is it mandatory that you do it manually?

Comment: What is the type of the image you read?

Comment: Try to be more specific. What is exactly wrong with the result?

Comment: @ddriver I would like to optimize it, the opencv resize is very slow on ARM for a large image.

Comment: For a start, `srcPtr+=2;` is not correct when you are moving to the next row, since you need to skip one.

Comment: @Alex according to the code, is just a sample greyscale image

Comment: @Shahbaz is the for loop iteration size should be 4 for processing the whole row ? Is the dstImage should be allocated that it should be half of the srcImage to get good result ?

Comment: @Mahmoud, I mean BMP, JPG, or whatever.

Comment: The allocation of the `dstImage` seems all right. It'd be much simpler for you to use multiple loops to properly scan the source and calculate the destination image. By the way, I'm pretty sure opencv guys are pretty smart and they tried their best to implement a very optimized algorithm. Are you sure the problem of resizing large images is slow because of opencv? It's very likely that it's in fact because the processor is simply too slow.

Comment: If you're averaging over 4 pixels, shouldn't you divide the value you place in dstPtr[0] by 4 (instead of 2), before casting it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's not much wrong in your code -- basically just keep proper track of the read/write pointer locations (remember to update with strides). This requires using 2 nested loops one way or another. (+ fix the divider to 4).

I've found the following approach useful: processing one row at a time has not much speed penalty, but allows easier integration of various *kernels*.

```
iptr=input_image;  in_stride = in_width;
optr=output_image; out_stride = out_width;
for (j=0;j<out_height;j++) {
    process_row(iptr, optr, in_width);  // in_stride is needed
    // as the function requires access to iptr+in_stride
    iptr+=in_stride * 2;
    optr+=out_stride;
}
```

Comment: I have updated the code according to yours. Is this all now correct ?

Comment: No -- and I too had an error, which you managed to find out. `optr=output_image;` naturally. The two missing things are that the strides differ for input/output images. And also, at the process_row function you got to advance to `iptr += 2;` every step. This is for the same reason there's `iptr += in_stride * 2;` in the outer loop.

Answer (score 1):

I see you are using Qt, so just in case you don't need to reinvent the wheel, QImage has a convenience function that will do resizing (effectively down-sampling) for you.

```
QImage smallImage = bigImage.scaled(bigImage.width() / 2, bigImage.heigth() / 2, Qt::KeepAspectRatio, Qt::SmoothTransformation);
```

In case QImage is too slow for you, you can also try using QPixmap which is generally faster.

Omitting `Qt::SmoothTransformation` will fall back to using the default `Qt::FastTransformation` which will be even faster.

Comment: @Mahmoud - what do you mean by slow? Did you test? Do you have results?